# WPF - Binding internal datagrid with external datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, grid, relativesource

Need a little help.
In XAML, I've got the following layout:

```xml
<DataGrid Name="outerGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding fullData}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Something"  Binding="{Binding something}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid Name="innerData" ItemsSource="{Binding innerData}">
                     <DataGrid.Columns>
                          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Something"  Binding="{Binding something}" />
                     </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
          </DataTemplate>
     </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid Name="fullDetailGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding ??????? }">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Something"  Binding="{Binding something}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is the structure that I would like to preset, I know that if I do a three level depth grid this is easy, but I have a business requirement to have this kind of structure.

Is there anyway to do this without code behind and just do a relativesource binding of the inner grid

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue with a topic where my ItemsSource of a parent control had been bound to a property within my ViewModel (which was bound to the DataContext), but where I needed the full ViewModel to bind to another property there. It then had the following syntax (in xaml):

```xml
    <TextBlock Text="Documents" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=PageRoot, Path=DataContext.IsVisible }" />
```

As you can see, I bound my item to the PageRoot (where the DataContext had been bound to the ViewModel) and then directed it to my boolean indicating the visibility (with a converter obviously, but I removed that for reading purposes).

For your purpose: You could try binding the ItemsSource of your fullDetailGrid to the innerData source (though you might use to define that Element with x:Key instead of Name only). Then you could point it to the property which holds the desired value for your fullDataGrid. Syntax would be more or less the following (assuming you would use x:Key innerData on the nested datagrid):

```
    <DataGrid Name="fullDetailGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=innerData, Path=YourDataContext.YourCollection }">
```